# Wait for the output of a "confirmation modal" to compute a reactive value in an RShiny application

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, reactive

I would like to build an RShiny application of this type:

- the user enters a numerical input and then launches the calculations with a button
- if the numerical input is below a threshold the calculations are launched automatically
- if the numerical input is above the threshold, a modal box appears to tell the user that it will take time. He can then cancel (no calculation is launched) or continue anyway.

Here is a schematic example of an application.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Ask the user for confirmation"),
  numericInput(
    inputId = "number", label = "Enter your number", value = 5,
    min = 1, max = 10, step = 1
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "start",
    label = "Start"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  random <- eventReactive(input$start, {
    
    if (input$number > 6){
      ask_confirmation(
        inputId = "myconfirmation",
        title = "Want to confirm ?",
        text = "It will take a long time..."
      )
      req(input$myconfirmation)
    } 
    rnorm(input$number)
    
  })
  
  output$res <- renderPrint(random())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, in this example, the computation of my reactive variable `random()` is not at all conditional on the user's response in the modal box but rather on the past states of the variable.
I specify that I used the `ask_confirmation` function of the shinyWidgets package here for its explicit character but I also tried functions of the basic `shiny package`, or of `shinyalert`. I feel I should probably decouple by creating `observe`or `observeEvent` blocks outside my reactive variables but I haven't managed to do that yet. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!